# Excel VBA to copy Word Doc into Outlook - Images Disappear

Tags: excel, vba, image, outlook, ms-word

I am using the technique of copying the word document to the clipboard and then pasting it into the body of the Outlook object.  It works like a charm when I run the code on a Windows 10 machine, however, when I try to run the exact code with a copy of the same word document on a Windows 7 machine, everything but the images gets copied.  Any ideas what is causing this and if there is a work-around?

Appreciate any ideas.  I'm getting googled out and haven't found a solution.

Here is the code
To place on clipboard

```
'
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wd.documents.Open(WordFile)
    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close
    Set wd = Nothing

'   Here is the code to setup and send email

'
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
'
            With OutMail
'
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = TSubject
'
'          Customize Saluation
'
                cusname = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value
                SalLines = Salutation & " " & cusname & vbCrLf
'
                .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText

                Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
                editor.Content.Paste
 '     Without the following line the content does not appear
                .Display
'
                .htmlbody = SalLines & .htmlbody
'
'
                .Display
                .Send
'
                'You can add files also like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
'
'
            End With
```

Comment: You might need to set `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tim.  This seems to be related to images in cells which is not my issue.  Regardless, I am a rookie so I tried it anyway and unfortunately it did not work.  The images are in the word document.

Comment: Sorry I missed this was copying from Word.  Does it work if you copy-paste manually?

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Yes Tim it works manually.  Code has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  By adding an additional Bodyformat = olformathtml just before inserting the salutation everything works perfectly.